# Integral over a triangle using Green's theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to find $\displaystyle \oint_{C} (y-\sin{x})\;{dx}+\cos{x}dy$ where $C$ is the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (0, \frac{\pi}{2}), (1, \frac{\pi}{2}).$

What's troubling me is determining $C$. I thought I should say $0 \le y \le x$, and $0 \le x \le \pi/2$, and integrating with respect to $y$ first, but the answer comes out wrong. Isn't that the same triangle?

Comment: It looks right, but of course it depends on what you integrate. What is your integrand?

Comment: @Kuifje My integrand is $-(\sin{x}+1)$. If integrate that with respect to $y$ first and then with respect to $x$ I get $-(1+\pi^2/8)$, which is not the given answer of $-2/\pi-\pi/4$.

Comment: Ok. I just realized your bounds are incorrect. Draw the triangle, you will see that it should be $x\pi/2\le y\le \pi/2$ and $ 0\le x\le  1$.

Comment: @Kuifje Thanks. Is my triangle different to the one given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limits should be $(\pi/2 )x \leq y \leq \pi/2$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind saying a few words as to how you got these limits?

Comment: I would have but I am on mobile so can't elaborate. You can see general info about finding limits for double integration here http://mathinsight.org/double_integral_examples.